# Identify this blown up IC?

Tags: identification

Marking is IOR209M.
But I cannot find any datasheet.
My best guess is a SOP8/SOIC8 MOSFET.
[image]

Comment: Was it interacting with a shorted capacitor?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Apparently yes. Power supply failed and this happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an Infineon (International Rectifier) Dual MOSFET, P/N [IRF7313](https://www.mouser.ca/c/?q=IRF7313)

Comment: Thanks a lot...